# operator [] error invalid types 'Config*[const char [8]]' for array subscript

Tags: c++

Why this wrong?

-- Config.h

```
class Config: {
    public:
        void read();
        std::string operator[](std::string key);
        ....
};
```

-- app.cpp

```
Config *config;
config->read();
std::string a=config["sysname"]; // this line error
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`config` is a pointer, so  syntactically valid ways of calling its `operator[]` would be

```
(*config)["sysname"]
```

or

```
config->operator[]("sysname")
```

The reason for the confusing error message is that it is syntactically correct to call `operator[]` on pointers, but the parameter is an integral type:

```
int* p;
p[42];
```

Note that in your code `config` does not point to a valid `Config` object.